# Cassandra warning: Aggregation query used without partition key

Tags: cassandra

When I run a count query against C*, I get result with a warning:

> cqlsh:my_keyspace> SELECT count(*) from user;
>
> count
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  1
> ```
>
> (1 rows)
>
> Warnings : Aggregation query used without partition key

Warning is because C* has to do scan across all nodes.

But when I do this query:

> cqlsh:my_keyspace> SELECT * FROM user;
>
> last_name | first_name | title

> -----------+------------+-------
> Doe       |     John   |   Mr.
>
> (1 rows)

This query doesn't show me a warning. Isn't this also supposed to scan all nodes?

Comment: You can see more about aggregation here: https://www.batey.info/cassandra-udas.html. Depending that you are trying to do, this warning is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both queries do a full table scan but the former uses an aggregate function while the latter doesn't.

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function -- it returns a final count by aggregating all rows in the query. This is the reason `SELECT COUNT(*)` generates a warning while `SELECT *` doesn't. Cheers!